# Complex LINQ query vs Complex for loops

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, dictionary

Right now I have this complex function, I have a list of MainObjects(call them MO) and for each of these objects I have to loop over a list of objects(call them C) with a title, a status and a list of sub-objects (call them E). The function loops over these sub-objects(E) and uses it's title and quantity properties.

The goal of the function is to create a dictionary(D1), where the Key is a C(title) and the Values is another dictionary(D2), where the Key is E(title) and the Values yet another dictionary(D3), where the Key is C(status) and the value E(quantity).
So in the end I will have all (unique) C(title)'s wherein I can see all (unique) E(title)'s wherein I can see all different C(status)'s and the E(quantity) of these statuses (with as extra challenge if 2 E(quantity)'s would have the same status with the same title on the same course they should be added to each other and then put in as value).

I made this all work fine.

However. The function is big and hard to understand, so I'm looking for a more approachable way of dealing with this problem. 
One of these ways was supposed to be LINQ. However, I have little to no knowledge about this and for a massively complex function as this I can hardly understand how to deal with this in LINQ.
I'm also concerned about performance since this WPF project is heavily dependable on user-experience. So I'm not sure if LINQ would actually make things faster, slower or same.

Here is where you guys come in.

- Is LINQ a better way to deal with this problem?
- Is the performance similar to the one of my function?
- Is the LINQ query more understandable?
- Is there an alternative way of dealing with this complex function
  rather then the 2 methods I'm describing?

---

Underneath you will find the function I used to deal with this function my way.

It is done in 3 steps:

1. Step1: Loop the MO's, C's, E's and create a list of dictionaries.
2. Step2: Join the duplicate key's of the result of step1 and create a
   first stage dictionary.
3. Step3: Split the deeper dictionaries so that
   we can use the E object as intended.

Result: has been put in the 'final' object. A list of dictionaries with as keys C(title) and values a list of dictionaries. This list of dictionaries with as keys E(title) and values a Dictionary. This Dictionary has as keys C(status) and values E(quantity). This E(quantity) is a combined value of each quantity of each E of the same C(status) for a same C.

---

```
        //DateTime start = DateTime.Now; //start performance test

        //start -> step 1
        List<Dictionary<string/*C(title)*/, Dictionary<int/*C(status)*/, List<E>>>> firstResultList = new List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<E>>>>();

        foreach(MO mo in listOfMOs)
        {
            foreach (C c in mo.listOfCs)
            {
                Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<E>>> D1 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<E>>>();

                int cStatus = c.status;
                Dictionary<int, List<E>> D2 = new Dictionary<int, List<E>>();

                List<E> eList = new List<E>();

                foreach (E e in c.listOfEs)
                {
                    eList.Add(e);
                }

                D2.Add(cStatus, eList);

                D1.Add(c.Title, D2);

                firstResultList.Add(D1);
            }
        }
        //firstResultList = step1 results
        //Console.WriteLine(firstResultList.ToString());
        //

        //step1 -> step2
        Dictionary<string/*C(title)*/, List<Dictionary<int/*C(status)*/, List<E>>>> groupedDict = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<int, List<E>>>>();

        foreach (Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<E>>> dict in firstResultList)
        {
            List<Dictionary<int, List<E>>> listje;

            if(groupedDict.ContainsKey(dict.Keys.ElementAt(0)))
            {
               listje = groupedDict[dict.Keys.ElementAt(0)];

            }
            else
            {
                listje = new List<Dictionary<int, List<E>>>();
            }

            listje.Add(dict[dict.Keys.ElementAt(0)]);
            groupedDict[dict.Keys.ElementAt(0)] = listje;
        }
        //groupedDict = step2 results
        //Console.WriteLine(groupedDict.ToString());
        //

        //step2 -> step3
        Dictionary<string/*C(title)*/, List<Dictionary<string/*E(title)*/, Dictionary<int/*C(status)*/, int/*E(quantity)*/>>>> final = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>>>>();

        int index = 0;
        foreach (List<Dictionary<int, List<E>>> list in groupedDict.Values)
        {
            //Within one unique C
            List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>>> eStatusQuantityList = new List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>>>();

            foreach (Dictionary<int, List<E>> dict in list)
            {
                foreach (List<E> eList in dict.Values)
                {
                    foreach(E e in eList)
                    {
                        if (eStatusQuantityList.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>> dict2 in eStatusQuantityList)
                            {
                                Dictionary<int, int> statusQuantityDict;

                                if (dict2.ContainsKey(e.Title))
                                {
                                    statusQuantityDict = dict2[e.Title];
                                    //int quantity = statusQuantityDict.value//statusQuantityDict[dict.Keys.ElementAt(0)];
                                    int quantity = 0;
                                    int value;
                                    bool hasValue = statusQuantityDict.TryGetValue(dict.Keys.ElementAt(0), out value);
                                    if (hasValue) {
                                        quantity = value;
                                    } else {
                                        // do something when the value is not there
                                    }

                                    statusQuantityDict[dict.Keys.ElementAt(0)] = quantity + e.Quantity;
                                    dict2[e.Title] = statusQuantityDict;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    statusQuantityDict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
                                    statusQuantityDict.Add(dict.Keys.ElementAt(0), e.Quantity);
                                    dict2.Add(e.Title, statusQuantityDict);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>> test = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>>();
                            Dictionary<int, int> test2 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
                            test2.Add(dict.Keys.ElementAt(0), e.Quantity);
                            test.Add(e.Title, test2);
                            eStatusQuantityList.Add(test);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //ending
            string key = groupedDict.Keys.ElementAt(index);
            final[key] = eStatusQuantityList;
            index++;
            //
        }
        //final contains step3 results
        //Console.WriteLine(final.ToString());
        /*
        for (int i = 0; i<final.Keys.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(final.Keys.ElementAt(i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < final.Values.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(final.Values.ElementAt(i));
        }
        */
        //

        //TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now - start; //end performance test
        //Console.WriteLine("That took " + duration.TotalMilliseconds + " ms"); //performance test results //60.006 is fine, 600.006 is OOM. //Our range of objects is max. 300 MO's though
```

As you can see this is a hell of a function. But it works fine (2-5ms (avg. 2.5) for our max target of MO's). But I can see people (other then myself) messing up when they have to readjust this function for some reason. So any improvement in maintainability or readability would be cool.

Comment: I think http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate site for such questions

Comment: @Matt I have no clue what your getting at xD.

Comment: You know, meaningful type and variable names would go a long way towards making that wall of code more understandable. Reading `E`, `D1`, `D2`, etc. gave me bad flashbacks of writing BASIC on my old TRS-80.

Comment: @JimMischel haha I know, in my real code they all have meaningful names. But given the fact that those names are not relevant to the question and maybe distract from the problem I left them out.

Answer (score 1):

- Is LINQ a better way to deal with this problem?

Better is subjective. Better looking? Better performance? Better (as in easier) understanding?

- Is the performance similar to the one of my function?

LINQ performance is usually not quite as good as doing it manually, however there is always a trade off because LINQ can be (not always) easier to understand.

- Is the LINQ query more understandable?

It can be. But if you've ever used reSharper where it looks at your code and says it can turn it into a LINQ query then you'll know that sometimes it makes it less understandable.

- Is there an alternative way of dealing with this complex function
  rather then the 2 methods I'm describing?

Mix-n-match? You can hand-code performance critical parts and leave the rest in LINQ. But to find the performance critical parts you should use a profiler rather than just guessing.

Comment: Unfortunately I have never used ReSharper before. Will the trial version have the same effect on my project (so I can actually make out if it's useful to me)? I have tried to at least make step2 a LINQ statement, but I have failed to do so in my inexperience using LINQ. I'm willing to make a trade-off to LINQ if the code becomes more readable/maintainable. Right now, this function works at 2-5ms (avg 2.5ms) for the maximum expected MO's, and it won't be as often used that it would hinder UI.

Comment: reSharper's trial is fully functional for 30 days. Your code won't rely on it so it is safe to remove afterwards (but you might find it sufficiently useful that you want to keep it)

Comment: Downloaded ReSharper, and it only says at one place that I could replace it with LINQ. That was, "foreach (List<E> eList in dict.Values){foreach(E e in eList)" to "dict.Values.SelectMany(eList => eList)". Does this mean LINQ is no option for my algorithm?

Comment: No, it just means that reSharper did not detect any common patterns that can easily be refactored automatically by it.